# Emphasis active panel in sublime text 3?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I use a touch pad with "doubke-tap to click" (which often fails). I'ld like to be able to style sublime text 3 to emphasise the active panel.

The selection opacity of the inactive panels does drop ~10%, but I couldn't find a colour in my theme to control this. So possibly the opacity is done programatically?

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside *Color Scheme* there are **files with *tmTheme* extension for every theme**. In those files you can change (or add) the properties **that controls inactive selection and active selection colors**.

I think you are looking for the *inactiveSelectionForeground* key. As a good example you can look at the *Monokai Bright* theme that has many properties that other themes doesn't seems to use.